# CSS flex wrap but no wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm running into an issue with flex-wrap. Where I need `flex-wrap: wrap` to take care that images wrap and don't run out of the container. I don't need wrap for a link. See my issue below, also my code is included in the post.

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8gqxpj15/18/)

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="tools">
    <a href="#">View details</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing dolor sit amet, consectetur.</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tools">
    <a href="#">View details</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  .image {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 5px;
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      &:not(:last-of-type) {
        margin-right: 5px;
      }
    }
  }
  .tools {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding

```
.box .image a:last-of-type {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.box .image {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box .image a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.box .image a:last-of-type {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.box .image a:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.box .tools {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="tools">
    <a href="#">View details</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing dolor sit amet, consectetur.</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tools">
    <a href="#">View details</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Min Width & Overflow Hidden

If you use `min-width` of `80px` which is your image box size and add `overflow:hidden`, everything fits in fine and there's nothing falling out.

To make the demo better, I made the other columns a `min-width` of `80px` and total `min-width` `160px` (2x80px) and gave all containers `overflow:hidden`.

### The Working Demo

See it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8gqxpj15/67/)

[image]

### The Code

**SCSS**

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  min-width:160px;
  overflow:hidden;
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;

  }
  .image {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    min-width:80px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 5px;

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      &:not(:last-of-type) {
        margin-right: 5px;

      }
    }
  }
  .tools {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-width:80px;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="tools">
    <a href="#">View details</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing dolor sit amet, consectetur.</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tools">
    <a href="#">View details</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tnx! However I think Paulie_D 's solution is better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52274324/1643487

Answer (score 0):

Please check my fiddle where I added my solution https://jsfiddle.net/Lazzaro/vkrh48tn/

I added new class

```
.image2 {
    width: 60%;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      &:not(:last-of-type) {
        margin-right: 5px;
      }
    }
  }
```

and it works

Comment: Sorry. I fixed it

Comment: I don't see the difference with my solution, besides this also not works.

Comment: Sorry. Jsfiddle was not saving my fiddle. You can try now. https://jsfiddle.net/Lazzaro/vkrh48tn/

Comment: Now it's working. However I think Paulie_D 's solution is better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52274324/1643487

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra container around the single box and the text. Define it as a flexbox and it will scale according to your desires.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.image {
  width: 60%;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
}

.image a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.image a:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.tools {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="tools">
    <a href="#">View details</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff"></a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing dolor sit amet, consectetur.</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tools">
    <a href="#">View details</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tnx! However I think Paulie_D 's solution is better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52274324/1643487

Comment: Paulie_D's solution is different. When you make the window small enough, the text will go below the square with his solution. In my case, it always stays beside it.